# Implement googlechart x-axis with dates from twig datetimes

Tags: javascript, datetime, twig, google-visualization

I have an array of the last 30 days with 2 keys for each day :

-date (datetime)

-count (integer)

[image]

I try to instanciate a google chart with the date in Xaxis and `count` in Yaxis but as soon as I try to loop on my array using twig, it seems that my datetime value is changed.

Here is the way I loop to add Rows on my graph in my `drawGraph()` function :

```
 function drawChart() {

      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'date', label: 'date'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Nombre d OF', label: 'Nb of'});


    {% for value in chartData.data %}
        console.log({{ value.date.format('Y-m-d') }});
        dataTable.addRow([new Date("{{ value.date.format('Y-m-d')| date("Y-m-d") }}".replace(/-/g,"/")), {{ value.count }}]);
    {% endfor %}

    var options = {
      title: 'Nombre d\'ordre de fabrication crées sur les 30 derniers jours ('+{{ chartData.info }}+')',
      hAxis: {title: 'Jours',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
```

I printed the date for each loop iteration and I get this result :

[image]

My question is : **Why is the date changed in my loop ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `2017 - 9 - 24` actualy is `1984`, you need to wrap your statement with quotes otherwise it gets treated as a subvision

`console.log('{{ value.date.format('Y-m-d') }}');`

Comment: Omg come on ... Thanks for the answer